# C++ idiom (or pattern) with interheritance from `NameBase` class to template `Name` class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, idioms

From time to time I come across the following (or something like that) class hierarchy in different C++ projects:

```
class DummyBase
{
   public:
      virtual ~DummyBase() {}
      virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Dummy : public DummyBase
{
    public:
        void doSomething() override
        {
            ...
        }

    private:
        T field;
};
```

Looks like as C++ idiom, pattern or maybe trick. Can you tell me the purpose of this contruction and what's the problem can be solved using it. I would be glad to read good articles or maybe books that describe it.

Comment: I don't understand the question :) You mean the naming convention? There is none. You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: @rifkin I want to know motivation of using this construction in projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is polymorphism based [type erasure](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/), it is often used for handling things like `std::function` or `std::any` which can store data of unrelated types in the exact same manner (e.g. function pointers and member function pointers for `std::function`).